# how to add search bar in django leaflet map

Tags: django, leaflet

I'm trying to use a map on my website and for that, I'm using the Django leaflet library
and I need to add a search bar to my map but I don't know how to do it
help me pls

[my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf8xM.jpg)

Comment: Ive never used leaflet, but can you put the search bar on the webpage beside the map?

Comment: yeah, I can but how can I send data from a form to map?